# How to set default elevation for ExtendedFloatingActionButton in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-material3

How can the default elevation for `ExtendedFloatingActionButton` be applied in Jetpack Compose so that a shadow can be seen? Understandably, the default resting level is number 3 and the default height is 6dp, but using `elevation = 6.dp` didn't work, so what other method is there?

```
ExtendedFloatingActionButton(
    text = { Text(text = "Button") },
    icon = { Icon(Icons.Filled.Add, "") },
    modifier = Modifier.clip(RoundedCornerShape(16.dp)),
    elevation = FloatingActionButtonElevation.?
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With **M3** the default elevation is defined by [`FloatingActionButtonDefaults.elevation()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/material3/FloatingActionButtonDefaults#elevation(androidx.compose.ui.unit.Dp,androidx.compose.ui.unit.Dp,androidx.compose.ui.unit.Dp,androidx.compose.ui.unit.Dp)).
If you want the default value just omit it. You can also override the default values with:

```
ExtendedFloatingActionButton(
    //..
    elevation = FloatingActionButtonDefaults.elevation(
        defaultElevation = 4.dp
    )
)
```

It [defines](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/material3/FloatingActionButtonDefaults#elevation(androidx.compose.ui.unit.Dp,androidx.compose.ui.unit.Dp,androidx.compose.ui.unit.Dp,androidx.compose.ui.unit.Dp)) the elevation of a `ExtendedFloatingActionButton` in different states

```
@Composable
fun elevation(
    defaultElevation: Dp = FabPrimaryTokens.ContainerElevation, //6.0.dp
    pressedElevation: Dp = FabPrimaryTokens.PressedContainerElevation, //6.0.dp
    focusedElevation: Dp = FabPrimaryTokens.FocusContainerElevation, //6.0.dp
    hoveredElevation: Dp = FabPrimaryTokens.HoverContainerElevation //8.0.dp
): FloatingActionButtonElevation
```

You can see in the [source code](https://github.com/androidx/androidx/blob/androidx-main/compose/material3/material3/src/commonMain/kotlin/androidx/compose/material3/tokens/FabPrimaryTokens.kt):

```
val ContainerElevation = ElevationTokens.Level3
val PressedContainerElevation = ElevationTokens.Level3
val FocusContainerElevation = ElevationTokens.Level3
val HoverContainerElevation = ElevationTokens.Level4
```

With **M2** the approach is similar and default values are defined by [`FloatingActionButtonDefaults.elevation()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/material/FloatingActionButtonDefaults#elevation(androidx.compose.ui.unit.Dp,androidx.compose.ui.unit.Dp,androidx.compose.ui.unit.Dp,androidx.compose.ui.unit.Dp)):

```
@Composable
fun elevation(
    defaultElevation: Dp = 6.dp,
    pressedElevation: Dp = 12.dp,
    hoveredElevation: Dp = 8.dp,
    focusedElevation: Dp = 8.dp,
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Defaults maybe in colors, elevations or anywhere is supposed to be used like this

```
ExtendedFloatingActionButton(
    text = { Text(text = "Button") },
    icon = { Icon(Icons.Filled.Add, "") },
    modifier = Modifier.clip(RoundedCornerShape(16.dp)),
    elevation = FloatingActionButtonDefaults.elevation(
        defaultElevation = 4.dp,
        pressedElevation = 8.dp,
        hoveredElevation = 2.dp,
        focusedElevation = 1.dp,
    ),
    onClick = {}
)
```

Comment: Are these the default `dp` values for a floating action button? Is there any document around stating what type of elevation should have which `dp` value?